# Sliders change to 0 upon change of slider value (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to increment/decrement a slider, but when I start dragging the slider the displayed value changes immediately to 0. Why is that? Here's my code (none of them work):

```
 - (IBAction)FrontLapChanged:(id)sender {
int myInt = (int) self.FrontlapSlider.value;
self.FrontlapMeasure.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", myInt];
 }
 - (IBAction)SidelapChanged:(id)sender {
float myFloat = self.SidelapSlider.value;
int value = (int)myFloat;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];
self.SidelapMeasure.text = string;
 }
```

Comment: Without setting the minimum and maximum values of the slider, you'll get the defaults, 0.0 and 1.0, respectively.  Casting slider's `float` value to an `int` abandons almost all of the value information, truncating the floats below 1.0 to 0.0.  What values do you expect from the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you either need to set the minimum and maximum values of your slider:

```
[self.SidelapSlider setMinimumValue:0.f];
[self.SidelapSlider setMaximumValue:100.f];

[self.FrontlapSlider setMinimumValue:0.f];
[self.FrontlapSlider setMaximumValue:100.f];
```

Or not cast the slider value (which will be between 0 and 1 by default), to an int. This is because casting to an int will lose precision. e.g. a float of 0.5 cast to int would be 0.

```
 - (IBAction)FrontLapChanged:(id)sender {
CGFloat value = self.FrontlapSlider.value;
self.FrontlapMeasure.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", value];
 }
 - (IBAction)SidelapChanged:(id)sender {
CGFloat value = self.SidelapSlider.value;
self.SidelapMeasure.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", value];
 }
```